# Simulated Annealing in C#

Tags: c#, simulated-annealing

I am using simulated annealing to solve a cryptanalysis problem and I've hit a brick wall. I cannot for the life of me get my probability function to operate correctly, it either takes a worse solution too often (so I bounce around a score of 0.03 and 0.2) or it doesn't take it often enough (so I get stuck at 0.35). I've looked around the internet but I only come across examples where the problems involve finding the MINIMUM value....my problem needs to find the MAXIMUM value, worst score is 0, best is 1.

I need advice on Temperature and what probability function I should use.

Comment: If you want to find the maximum value using a minimization algorithm, just negate your objective function, i.e. *max f(x) => min -f(x)*.

Comment: I'm sure this is helpful, I'm just not sure I understand, could you give me an example?

Comment: Normally, optimization algorithms search for the *minimum* of the objective function. If you want to use such an algorithm as-is on your *maximization* problem, ask the optimizer to *minimize* the negation of your objective function. For example, let's say that the objective function for which you want to find the *maximum* is `f(x)=1-(x-1)^2`. Then, ask the optimizer to *minimize* `-f(x)`. BTW, trimming the SA algorithm can be tedious. Is SA your only option, or would other derivative-free optimization algorithms also be OK?

Comment: I think I may be doing that at the moment, probability function now resembles Math.Exp(-((1-score)-(1-bestScore))/temperature) by taking the scores from 1 I am turning it into minimisation I think, yes?

Comment: If your goal is to *maximize* `score` then yes, it seems reasonable to apply `1-score` in a minimization algorithm. [Here](http://plato.asu.edu/sub/global.html) are some global optimization options, although I am not sure if any code is written in C#. [Here](http://plato.asu.edu/sub/nlounres.html#function) is a list of gradient-free algorithms that are not necessarily concerned with finding the global optimum. At least one of them, BOBYQA, is available in [C#](https://github.com/cureos/csbobyqa) (adapted to C# by me :-)

Comment: @AndersGustafsson - I think the community would be better served if you put this information in an actual answer. ;)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Done, although I felt a little reluctant to do so since I did not feel I completely addressed the question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Simulated Annealing article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) provides some general guidance on how SA temperatures should be initialized and decreased. Efficient selection of these parameters is normally very problem specific and may need to be identified through tedious trial-and-error.

Normally, optimization algorithms search for the *minimum* of the objective function. If you want to use such an algorithm as-is on your *maximization* problem, ask the optimizer to *minimize* the *negation* of your objective function. For example, let's say that the objective function for which you want to find the *maximum* is `f(x)=score`. You should then request the optimizer to *minimize* `-f(x)`, i.e. `-score` (or, as you indicate in the comment above, `1-score`).

There are lots of simulated annealing and other global optimization algorithms available online, see for example [this](http://plato.asu.edu/sub/global.html) list on the Decision Tree for Optimization Software. Unfortunately these codes are normally not written in C#, but if the codes are written in Fortran or C it is normally fairly easy to interface with these codes via *P/Invoke*.

If you do not require that the optimizer necessarily find the global optimum, there are also some derivative-free optimizers listed [here](http://plato.asu.edu/sub/nlounres.html#function). At least one of these codes is available in a C# version, namely [BOBYQA](https://github.com/cureos/csbobyqa) (in fact, this algorithm has been adapted to C# by me :-).